# Excel - Count number of times specific values appear in a range of columns, minus duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Good morning!**

After having thoroughly searched for an answer, I come to the conclusion that I need some help :D

I would need a formula that allows to count the number of times different values appear in a range, and remove potential duplicates.

In order words, if i have the following values:

- A1 : "john"
- A2 : "mary"
- A3 : "pedro"

in the following cells

- B1 : ("john", "pedro", "james")
- B2 : ("john", "juan", "eve")
- B3 : ("eve", "therese")
- B4 : ("mary", "pedro", "helen")

I would want the formula to return "3" because my different values appear in only three columns.

I am currently using the following formula: 
**=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(B:B)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B:B,A1,"")))/LEN(A1))** but it only works for one value and not multiple values.

Any help on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if there is a simpler solution, I was kind of playing around with the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(A1:A3),B1:B4))*1,(A1:A3<>"")*1)>0))
```

The above entered as an array formula (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>; you know it was entered correctly if you see the braces (`{}`) after entering the formula:

[image]

Comment: Your current formula I believe could be simplified to `=COUNTIF(B1:B4,"*"&A1&"*")`

Comment: yours is working as well but it does not take into account the fact that you can have a range of different values. When I replace "A1" with an range like "A1:A3", it doesnt work. But thank you for sharing the formula! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>0,IF((COUNTIF($B$1:$B$4,"*"&A1&"*")>0)=TRUE,1,0),"")+IF(LEN(A2)>0,IF((COUNTIF($B$1:$B$4,"*"&A2&"*")>0)=TRUE,1,0),"")+IF(LEN(A3)>0,IF((COUNTIF($B$1:$B$4,"*"&A3&"*")>0)=TRUE,1,0),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I believe the problem was that there might be more values in column A, so doing it this way would be daunting.